# sugarCRM: How to redirect to external page after logout?

Tags: php, ajax, logout, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I am trying to redirect to a page on my external page, what I have tried till now is. Manually I added some files. 
In /custom/modules/Users/logic_hooks.php

```
<?php

    $hook_version = 1;
    $hook_array = Array();

    $hook_array['after_logout'] = Array();
    $hook_array['after_logout'][] = Array(
        //Processing index. For sorting the array.
        1,

        //Label. A string value to identify the hook.
        'after_logout example',

        //The PHP file where your class is located.
        'custom/modules/Users/logic_hooks_class.php',

        //The class the method is in.
        'logic_hooks_class',

        //The method to call.
        'after_logout_method'
    );

?>
```

And another file in In /custom/modules/Users/logic_hooks_class.php

```
<?php

    if (!defined('sugarEntry') || !sugarEntry) die('Not A Valid Entry Point');

    class logic_hooks_class
    {
        function after_logout_method($bean, $event, $arguments)
        {

        header('Location: http://raviranjan.info/');
        }

         function AfterLogout(&$bean, $event, $arguments)  
    {  
        SugarApplication::redirect('http://raviranjan.info/');  
    }  
    }

?>
```

So is there any other way to redirecting or just show something on screen before or after logging out from SugarCRM application.

Advance Thanks for any help.

Comment: you want to show message before redirection? and you need to use sugar "SugarApplication::redirect" not php functions because that is not according to Sugar  standards.

Comment: @Abdul, If you just tell me that how to show a message before redirection or how to show a message before logging out that will be helpful. Thanks for commenting.

Comment: The below answer by @Abdul is working but not a permanent solution according to SugarCRM point of view. So any one, please answer that how I can do above using logic hooks after_logout property. So guys help me out here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing this. Read following details:

1. show alert of any other type of message by handling click event of logout link. e.g. when user click that link then show alert of any other type of message.
2. after logout redirect user to your custom page( you can build custom entry point which will be accessible with auth=>false).
3. you can add any button or java-script to show message then redirect it to your target page.

Simple jquery selector, see following:

```
$("a.utilsLink").click(function(){

var r = confirm("Are you sure to logout?");
if (r == true) {
    console.log("yes is clicked");
} else {
     console.log("cancel is clicked...");
return false;    
}

});
```

Comment: code sample of step 1 will be helpful, and also if you specified where to add that code. I am new to sugar that's why I am struggling.

Comment: can you guide me where to put above code because I put it in my custom module under js file it is not showing any result? All though I very appreciate your enthusiast support.

Comment: inspect element and share html of "logout" link, i think you will need to change jquery selector.

Comment: how you are checking that "nothing is happening" ? you need to write your own logic. can you even code?

Comment: sorry for up vote I did you but they are not displaying yet, they will display when I will have 15 reputations. my log out anchor is like <a href="#logout/?clear=1" track="click:userAction-LBL_LOGOUT" tabindex="-1"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i>Log Out </a>

Comment: have you tried this code 
$(".fa-sign-out").click(function(){

var r = confirm("Are you sure to logout?");
if (r == true) {
    console.log("yes is clicked");
} else {
     console.log("cancel is clicked...");
return false;  
}

});

Comment: just change class name. that is so basic of java-script and jquery.

Comment: I know class selector and id selector. I am new to SugarCRM not jquery.  All-though your answers were very helpful I will tick mark when I completed it. Thank-you very much.